# Fluent NHibernate Projection.Conditional with only when true part

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need the following condition (in SQL) to fill a specific field in my resultset:

```
 CASE
 WHEN M.ID_ENTIDAD = m.ID_ENTIDAD_VENTA then EC.CLAVE_ENTIDAD
 END AS Contraparte }
```

If I use

```
var contraparte = Projections.Conditional(
                  Restrictions.EqProperty("EntidadOwner", "EntidadVenta"),
                  Projections.Property("enc.CvePrincipalMiembro"),
                   null);
```

That return an error.

Also if I use:

```
  *var contraparte = Projections.Conditional(
                            Restrictions.EqProperty("EntidadOwner", "EntidadVenta"),
                            Projections.Property("enc.CvePrincipalMiembro"),
                             Projection.Constant(a constant value);*
```

Apparently it is not possible to use this Conditional without ELSE part. that is nhibernate can not generate CASE without ELSE part.

It is possible to do this?? Please help me!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found self the response.

I took two actions:

One, add the following dummy field in the map class used in your query:

```
Map(x => x.Dummy).Nullable().Formula("NULL");
```

Second: I modified the conditional projection with the following code:

```
var contraparte = Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.EqProperty("EntidadOwner", "EntidadVenta"),
                        Projections.Property("enc.CvePrincipalMiembro"),
                        Projections.Property("Dummy"));
```

That was all! I hope that this help another people with the same problem.

Comment: +1 because of `.formula("NULL")`. I didn't knew that it could be done.